# Redirect taking into account string after slash with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to do some redirects with .htaccess, so what before was:
*api/projects.php*

Now should be: *api/index.php/projects*

So far I've used this:

`Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api/
RedirectMatch 301 /projects\.php$ /api/index.php/projects`

Which works, but if there's any slash with a string after *projects.php*, I also need to take it into account, for instance:

`api/projects.php/456` should now be: `api/index.php/projects/456`

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `RedirectMatch` rule to this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /projects\.php(/.*)?$ /api/index.php/projects$1
```